# Advanced configuration for CKEditor with Strapi

Tags: ckeditor, strapi

I followed [the guide](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-change-the-wysiwyg-in-strapi) to replace Strapi's WYSIWYG editor with CKEditor. This worked just fine.

After following [the guide on how to use CKEditor as React Component](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html) from CKEditor site, I expected CKEditor to load and function properly.

However, running `npm run build` failed with the following error:
`Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/mixins/_rwd.css' in 'C:\work\myProject\backend\node_modules\@ckeditor\ckeditor5-image\theme'`

**Code snippets**

**From package.json:**

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^18.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^2.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "^18.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^18.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^18.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^18.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^18.0.0",
    // ...a lot more additional plugins
```

**From C:\work\myProject\backend\extensions\content-manager\admin\src\components\CKEditor\index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat.js';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote.js';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold.js';
import CKFinder from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/src/ckfinder.js';
// ...a lot more components imports
```

...

```js
const editorConfig = {
  plugins: [
    Autoformat,
    BlockQuote,
    Bold,
    CKFinder,
    // ...the rest of the plugins
  ],
  toolbar: {
    items: [
      'undo',
      'redo',
      'CKFinder',
      '|',
      'heading',
      'fontFamily',
     //  ...the rest of the plugins
    ],
    image: {
      toolbar: [
        'imageTextAlternative',
        'imageStyle:full',
        'imageStyle:side'
    ]
  },
  table: {
    contentToolbar: [
      'tableColumn',
      'tableRow',
      'mergeTableCells',
      'tableCellProperties',
      'tableProperties'
    ]
  },
}
```

...

```js
const Editor = ({ onChange, name, value }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        data={value}
        config={editorConfig}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          const data = editor.getData();
          onChange({ target: { name, value: data } });
        }}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

**System**

- Node.js version: 13.5.0
- NPM version: 6.13.4
- Strapi version: 3.0.0-beta.19.3
- Operating system: Windows 10 Pro

The CKEditor guide suggests that I'm using the [Advanced Setup](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html). This setup requires a certain Webpack configuration for compiling .css files and .svg icons. But I'm not sure where is the Webpack file that I should edit and how should I do that. Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: Currently it is not possible to extend the webpack config. The only way you can achieve advanced configurations is by building the editor separately take a look at this repository https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor-build-with-simple-upload-provider-strapi it might help you

Comment: @soupette Thank you for your reply! I did manage to get the classic configuration, the problem is I really need the advanced one, as it has so many plugins that I have to use. But as far as I can see - I really need to configure it in Webpack. I don't see any other way to include these plugins in the SKEditor config. Now by saying "currently", does that mean that you're planning to include such option in future releases?

Comment: Well currently what you can do is to create package where you will be able to set a custom webpack config and then, you can require your built module in your admin panel. Here's the repo link https://github.com/JelmerV-WFC/ckeditor5-build-classic and the related github issue https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4369

Comment: The PR is not merged yet but the other would be to use the Media Library component in the editor. Here's the PR with the upcoming documentation: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/5755

Comment: Oh, this is also great, thanks! Can't wait to see what could be done with that! Meanwhile I'm trying to customize the above mentioned repo, but again running into some problems with it. But I opened a new question for that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137997/customizing-ckeditor-for-strapi-gives-ckeditor-duplicated-modules-error

Comment: we have added the ability to customise the webpack config : https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/admin-panel/custom-webpack-config.html

Comment: @soupette Awesome! Will check it out in the next sprint! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```js
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
```

To

```js
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
```

Reference: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html