# Customizing CKEditor for Strapi gives "ckeditor-duplicated-modules" error

Tags: ckeditor, strapi

I tried to modify [this](https://github.com/JelmerV-WFC/ckeditor5-build-classic) repo to customize CKEditor I want to use in my Strapi project. I added a lot more plugins, this is what my ckeditor.js file looks like:

```js
import ClassicEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';

import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment.js';
import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat.js';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote.js';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold.js';
import CKFinder from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/src/ckfinder.js';
import CKFinderUploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter.js';
import EasyImage from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image/src/easyimage';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import FontBackgroundColor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontbackgroundcolor.js';
import FontColor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontcolor.js';
import FontSize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontsize.js';
import FontFamily from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontfamily.js';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading.js';
import HorizontalLine from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-horizontal-line/src/horizontalline.js';
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image.js';
import ImageCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption.js';
import ImageResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize.js';
import ImageStyle from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle.js';
import ImageToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar.js';
import ImageUpload from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload.js';
import Indent from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indent.js';
import IndentBlock from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indentblock.js';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic.js';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link.js';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list.js';
import MediaEmbed from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembed.js';
import MediaEmbedToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembedtoolbar.js';
import PageBreak from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-page-break/src/pagebreak.js';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import PasteFromOffice from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/src/pastefromoffice';
import SimpleUploadAdapterStrapi from 'ckeditor5-upload-strapi/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapterstrapi';
import SpecialCharacters from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacters.js';
import SpecialCharactersEssentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersessentials.js';
import SpecialCharactersArrows from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersarrows.js';
import SpecialCharactersCurrency from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterscurrency.js';
import SpecialCharactersLatin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterslatin.js';
import SpecialCharactersMathematical from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharactersmathematical.js';
import SpecialCharactersText from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters/src/specialcharacterstext.js';
import Strikethrough from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/strikethrough.js';
import Subscript from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/subscript.js';
import Superscript from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/superscript.js';
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table.js';
import TableCellProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tablecellproperties';
import TableProperties from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tableproperties';
import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar.js';
import Title from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/title.js';
import TodoList from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/todolist';
import Underline from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/underline.js';
import UploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter';

export default class AdvancedEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {}

AdvancedEditor.builtinPlugins = [
    Essentials,
    UploadAdapter,
    Alignment,
    Autoformat,
    Bold,
    Italic,
    BlockQuote,
    CKFinder,
    CKFinderUploadAdapter,
    EasyImage,
    FontBackgroundColor,
    FontColor,
    FontFamily,
    FontSize,
    Heading,
    HorizontalLine,
    Image,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageResize,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    IndentBlock,
    Link,
    List,
    MediaEmbed,
    MediaEmbedToolbar,
    PageBreak,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromOffice,
    SimpleUploadAdapterStrapi,
    SpecialCharacters,
    SpecialCharactersEssentials,
    SpecialCharactersArrows,
    SpecialCharactersCurrency,
    SpecialCharactersLatin,
    SpecialCharactersMathematical,
    SpecialCharactersText,
    Strikethrough,
    Subscript,
    Superscript,
    Table,
    TableCellProperties,
    TableProperties,
    TableToolbar,
    Title,
    TodoList,
    Underline
];

AdvancedEditor.defaultConfig = {
    // ...many configurations here
    language: 'en'
};
```

I ran the "npm run build" command and then copied the generated file (with translations folder) to the `./extensions/content-manager/admin/src/components/CKEditor` folder and this is how I used it in the index.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { auth } from 'strapi-helper-plugin';
import AdvancedEditor from './ckeditor.js';

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  .ck-editor__main {
    min-height: 220px;
    > div {
      min-height: 220px;
    }
  }
`;

const Editor = ({ onChange, name, value }) => {

  const jwtToken = auth.getToken();

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <CKEditor
        editor={AdvancedEditor}
        data={value}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          const data = editor.getData();
          onChange({ target: { name, value: data } });
        }}
        config={{
          simpleUpload: {
            uploadUrl: `${strapi.backendURL}/upload`,
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + jwtToken
            }
          }
        }}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

Editor.propTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Editor
```

Now already in IDE (Webstorm) I receive a `Duplicated code fragment` warning. Build passed correctly though. But when I go into Admin Panel on the browser I see this error message:

`CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated.`

I did follow their instructions, deleted the `node_modules` folder and installed everything again, but still getting the same error.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally figured it out. The problem was in all the plugins with version 18.0.0

I guess they were the ones duplicating some modules. Once downgraded to version 15.0.0 - it all worked as it should!

Here's a link to [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Igal-Kleiner/ckeditor5-build-advanced)

And to [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor-advanced-build-with-simple-upload-provider-strapi)