# CKEditor5 Online Editor - How to configure a custom npm package for strapi

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ckeditor, strapi, ckeditor5

i use strapi and i want to change the default text editor with the ckeditor5 classic.
On the strapi website is a guide how to configure the default ckeditor5 classic for strapi.

[Strapi Guide](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-change-the-wysiwyg-in-strapi)

But there are some important tools missing so I want to build my custom fork of the ckeditor5 classic package.
I started with the ckeditor5 online builder. Downloaded the build package and want to import it in the strapi project.

[Online Builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)

My problems starting here.
First of all, how I can use a downloaded package in a project instead of download it over npm/yarn?

Package Structure:

1. build
2. sample
3. src
4. Licsence
5. package.json
6. webpack.config

I saw that package has no main command in the package.json. So an import in a node.js file to this package doesn't work. Here is my question, is this package i build with the online generator intended for  usage in a node project?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the truth, I don't know very well, I'm not an expert on the subject yet ... I'm really new and I'm working with strapi, but as I see these plugins have an install command with NPM. Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWb7q.png)

Try to download the plugins by NPM or Yarn and then import them as they say in this post: [Customizing CKEditor for Strapi gives "ckeditor-duplicated-modules" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137997/customizing-ckeditor-for-strapi-gives-ckeditor-duplicated-modules-error)